# A word denoting the status of concepts that are based on the property of "extension" such as "size", "shape" and "length"

Tags: single-word-requests, science, philosophy

It's in a philosophical context. It is evident that without extension, things can't have size, shape or length. Now I want to use a word that describes these latter concepts in term of their dependence on extension so that I can use the word in the following hypothetical context:

> Extension and its .... are properties of material entities.

I have already thought of "derivatives" but for some reason I thought there may be better words.

Comment: "dependents", perhaps?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "extension", which is a very abstract term (and therefore a very vague one, unless properly defined). Are you talking about continuous functions in ℝ³, for example? Or topological homogeneity? Or what? Material entities can have any property one wishes to assign them, after all; it isn't like there's a small fixed set for everything.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I am mainly intending its more abstract, metaphysical notions. See [Wikipedia: Extension (metaphysics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_(metaphysics))

Comment: Well, then, this isn't a question about English language and usage. For a specialized usage like that, there is no general English term.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Hmmm, I thought it is not that specialized. Extension is simply space or distance, without which there can be no shape, size or length since they all occur only in space (which is itself an extended thing). But thanks anyway!

Comment: ***embodiments***-

Comment: I'd say it's very abstract. Precisely because it's simple. Like aether, the medium that light makes waves in. Similarly abstract, but descriptive of real phenomena, are [the semantic properties of _entities](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf)_ (i.e, what nouns refer to), as categorized by Frawley. These include '7. Physical Properties
7.1. Extendedness (often found in classifiers), 
7.1.1. Dimensionality/Shape, 
7.1.2. Direction'. In fact, classifiers are a good thing to look into, if you want metaphysical eigenconcepts.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, *size* (including *length*) and *shape* are ***manifestations*** of *extension*.

> Extension and its ***manifestations*** are properties of material
>   entities.

Collins:

> **[manifestation](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manifestation)**
>   *countable noun*
>   A *manifestation* of something is one of the different ways in which it can appear.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Comment: Yes! "Manifestation" also came to my mind, and considering your reaffirming suggestion, it is so far the closest word. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

***Dimension***

> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dimension)
>
> NOUN
>
> usually *dimensions*
> A measurable extent of some kind, such as length, breadth, depth, or height.
>
> > - ‘the final dimensions of the pond were 14 ft. x 8 ft’
> > - ‘the drawing must be precise in dimension’

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extension), in Physics Philosophy, **extension** is the property of occupying space. One could argue that size, shape, structure, etc. are **elaborations** of extension. Also from OD:

> [**elaboration**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elaboration):
>   the process of developing or presenting a theory, policy, or system in
>   further detail

Your example:

> Extension and its **elaborations**, such as size, shape, and
>   structure, are properties of material entities.